# Go <-chan overhead

Tags: go

I have been trying to understand channels in Go for a while now. But one thing makes me wonder. What happens exactly when you call,

```
for {
  select {
    case <-chan:
  }
}
```

Does it check the chan every for iteration for updates? How would it compare to a normal `case i = int:`, or a `case atomic.LoadUint64() = uint64:` performance-wise?

Answer (score 3):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Select statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)
>
> Execution of a "select" statement proceeds in several steps:
>
> 1. For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send
>      statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering
>      the "select" statement. The result is a set of channels to receive
>      from or send to, and the corresponding values to send. Any side
>      effects in that evaluation will occur irrespective of which (if any)
>      communication operation is selected to proceed. Expressions on the
>      left-hand side of a RecvStmt with a short variable declaration or
>      assignment are not yet evaluated.
> 2. If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection.
>      Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen. If there
>      is no default case, the "select" statement blocks until at least one
>      of the communications can proceed.
> 3. Unless the selected case is the default case, the respective communication operation is executed.
> 4. If the selected case is a RecvStmt with a short variable declaration or an assignment, the left-hand side expressions are
>      evaluated and the received value (or values) are assigned.
> 5. The statement list of the selected case is executed.

Go `select` statement behavior is defined in The Go Programming Language Specification. `<-chan` is evaluated once.

> For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive
>   operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send
>   statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering
>   the "select" statement.

Comment: What about the <-chan specifier, what's it's overhead if the channel hasn't received anything yet (how does it compare to, for example: i = value in term of performance)

Comment: @Whiteclaws: Generally, a channel receive will take longer than an assignment. That may or may not be significant in the larger scheme of things. For particular cases, run a benchmark: [Benchmarks, Package testing](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/).

Answer (score 2):

The *implementation* of channels is not defined by the language specification (and will never be), so a particular implementation is free to do anythng it wants *while it conforms to the specification.*

On the other hand, accessing a channel behaves like accessing a mutex so I beleive internally Go arranges to use system-provided means of blocking on an appropriate resource.  Think of `WaitForMultipleObjects()` on Windows, futexes on Linux and so on.

In other words, while the `for { select { case <-chan: ... } }` construct looks like *busy waiting* on the objects in those `case` labels, in fact it is not: the compiler leverages the system's means of making the Go runtime scheduler be notified when some of those resources becomes available.

Comment: An implementation must conform to the specification.

Comment: @peterSO, sure but as I read the OP's question, they did not ask about the specification but rather about how this stuff *actually* works. Hence my stab at explaining it. I've updated my answer to mention this bit, just in case.